# Can the sum of these two quantiles be negative?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, quantiles

We already know that in a two sample t test, given alpha and beta, we can compute sample size:

$$
N=\frac{4 \sigma^{2}\left(z_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}+z_{1-\beta}\right)^{2}}{\Delta^{2}}
$$

Now if we want to get power, given alpha and sample size, we just need to solve for power in the above equation.

However, when we take square root, how can we guarantee that $z_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}+z_{1-\beta}$ is positive?

I know in most cases $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are small so $z_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}+z_{1-\beta}$ must be positive. But what if there is a terrible test? Could it be negative?

Comment: This formula is for estimating sample size for given Type I and II errors in a **z-test**, not a t-test. Power and sample size computations for t tests require use of a noncentral t distribution. // Also, when used for a z-test the two quantities you mention are in the _upper_ tail of standard normal; as such they must exceed 0 and tend to exceed 1.5 in practical use, so you wouldn't need to worry about negative values.

Comment: @BruceET Thanks! But actually although $z_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}$ must be positive, what if $\beta>0.5$ such that $z_{1-\beta}<0$?

Comment: That's still not a problem, because necessarily $\beta \ge \alpha/2,$ whence the sum of the Z scores is always positive.